# Ideas About How Speed Up Page With Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, dom, vue.js

I've built that page. and it's using the framework vue.js 2 and Jquery.
It's blowing out my head because that page is very slow.
Could you expert guys help me with some idea about how to speed up it.
Thank Guys.

The page is that:
http://softwareapqp.com.br/teste/public/pecas/21/cronograma
you can click in "editar" button and in blue button which opens you can try to drap and drop it. You'll see how it's realy slow.
or, you can click in "Desenvolvimento Fornecedores" or "adicionar atividade" and see how the modal is slow to open.

Comment: **1.** Open Chrome DevTools; **2.** Select the "Audit" tab; **3.** Select "Reload Page and Audit on Load"; **4.** Click "Run"

Comment: thanks man. do you have some idea about how to optimize that drag and drop? it's frozing a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Had a quick look, your right it's not a seamless experience.  It doesn't look like a problem with JavaScript, this is more of a UI/UX problem. One thing stood out, you have a horizontal scroll inside a vertical scroll inside the vertical scroll of the page itself.

Maybe you can have panels with left right panning navigation arrows that asynchronouously loads content when the user clicks the arrows instead of scrollable windows. This way, you're only loading what the user can see and scrolling the page wouldn't be such a pain. Only load the data/HTML when it's useful, otherwise it's just bloating up your memory/DOM.